# NullPointer Exception when setting the Adapter for a ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

```
    `Adapter class :::


    public class YAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        ArrayList<String> items;
        Context context;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView yName;
        }

        public YAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> items) {
            super(context, R.layout.single_item_list_row, items);
            this.context=context;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int arg0) {
            return items.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }





    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item_list_row,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.yName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
           } 
                else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                try
                {
                    if(items.get(position) != null)
                        holder.yName.setText(items.get(position));  
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                      Log.e("ERROR","Adapter error in generating view);
                }
                return convertView;
            }

        }

        Activity Class ::



        public class DemoActivity extends Activity {


            ListView listView;
            ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
            YAdapter adapter;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


            }
                @Override
            public void onResume() {
                super.onResume();
                temp.add("one");
                temp.add("two");
                temp.add("three");
                temp.add("four");
                adapter = new YAdapter(DemoActivity.this , temp);


                **listView.setAdapter(adapter);**  -- exception

            }
            }

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

this line causes an exception.
```

when i try setting adapter to list it gives error if i remove this line no error is displayed and also no components on screen are displayed only a black screen appears.

What i have coded is shown below bt i am getting null pointer exception .Please tell me what i have missed ?

Comment: I think its there below the adapter class

Comment: lol what is it??? Who commet my answer???????????????????????????

Comment: he is using androidannotations http://code.google.com/p/androidannotations/wiki/LayoutAndViews

Comment: opps I noticed @ViewById(R.id.list) but you also have @EActivity(R.layout.main)........... –

Comment: lol, he could add to my anwer comment and i would delete my topic myself...

Comment: @Roshni why you deleted  @EActivity(R.layout.main)and @ViewById(R.id.list)?.

Comment: Sorry but i think @user370305 answer is right .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as using  `@ViewById(R.id.list) so no need to findViewById`.....

issue is due

```
adapter = new YAdapter(YellowPagesActivity.this , temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at this line, your activity name,

```
public class Activity extends Activity {
```

and at adapter line,

```
 adapter = new YAdapter(YellowPagesActivity.this , temp);
```

So what is **YellowPagesActivity.this** ?